# SAS - Using If-then-do in macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm making a macro to pull tables from a database, then export some of those tables using `proc export`. I'm doing this by using an if-then-do statement to check if the macro variable equals a string, and if it does then that table gets exported. Here's my code:

```
%MACRO query(x);
  proc sql;
    connect using conn;
    create table &x. as select * from connection to conn
      (select * 
      from db.&x.);
    disconnect from conn;
  quit;

  %if &x. = "AddressCategory" %then 
    %do;
      proc export data = &x. outfile="C:\path\&x..txt" dbms=dlm replace; delimiter="|"; 
      run;
    %end;
%mend query;
%query(AddressCategory);
```

This produces a dataset named `AddressCategory`, but the export doesn't work. any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I realized the problem was that I needed to add the option "minoperator" to the macro!

Comment: That doesn't make sense with the code shown. You need to modify your `%IF`  condition, `%if &x = AddressCategory` or `%if "&x" = "AddressCategory"`.

Answer (score 0):

> then export some of those tables

Within the macro you likely don't want to check for the item to export by name.  If you do, the macro will grow to contain a large number of ifs checking which argument is appropriate for export.

A better macro would have an additional `export=` parameter that defaults to `0`, and the callee sets it to `1` for the data sets to be exported

```
%MACRO fetcher (
  remoteLibref=conn, 
  remoteSchema=db, 
  object=, 
  outlib=work, 
  out=&object, 
  export=0, 
  outpath=C:\exports\&remoteSchema,
  outname=&object
);
  proc sql;
    connect using &remoteLibref;
    create table &outlib..&out as select * from connection to &remoteLibref
    ( select * 
      from &remoteSchema..&object
    );
    disconnect from &remoteLibref;
  quit;

  %if &export %then %do;
      proc export 
        dbms=dlm
        data=&outlib..&out. 
        replace outfile="&outpath.\&object..txt"
      ;
        delimiter="|"; 
      run;
  %end;
%mend fetcher;
```

The invoke it for your various remote objects, specifying explicitly the ones to export

```
libname conn sqlserver … connection string … ;

%fetcher(object=AddressCategory, export=1)
%fetcher(object=AddressBook)
%fetcher(object=PreferenceCategory, export=1)
%fetcher(object=PreferenceItems)
%fetcher(object=PreferenceProperties)
%fetcher(object=Payouts, export=1)
%fetcher(object=Payouts, RemoteSchema=DBX, export=1, outname=hidden-payouts)
```